# While using the YouTube api, the loadvideo function wont work unless I alert the video id first

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

```
function playPlaylist(trackstemp) {
    trackstemp = trackstemp.split(' ');
    for (i=0; i < trackstemp.length; i++){
        tracks[i] = trackstemp[i];
    }
    numoftracks = tracks.length - 1;
    currenttrack = 0;
    loadNewVideo(tracks[currenttrack])
}

function loadNewVideo(id) {
ytplayerid.loadVideoById(id, 0);
}
```

I have a prev() and next() function that work just fine by calling loadNewVideo(tracks[currenttrack]), but the initial video only works if I alert(id) within the loadNewVideo() function.

Any clue to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [onYouTubePlayerReady](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#EventHandlers) which tells you when the player is ready?

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(){
    //Call you first track here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely the effect of the `alert` is to delay the execution of `ytplayerid.loadVideoById(id, 0);` so that it satisfies a race condition in your code - for example, the function doesn't exist yet, or some dependency in the function is not yet settled.

Make sure that the first `loadNewVideo` happens after all other scripts are loaded and the DOM is ready (ie, by attaching the function to the `window.load` event).

Answer (score 0):

Separate this out and put in that head in its own script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerid) { 
    ytp = document.getElementById('ytplayer');      
    ytp.mute();
  };
</script>
```